# Compute mean and standard deviation of multidimensional vector along a certain axis in C++ using STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, statistics, mean

I have a two- and three-dimensional vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> v2;
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> v3;
```

How can I compute the mean and standard deviation along a certain axis unsing only STL functions? Currently I'm using a pure C approach where I iterate over every element using two or three for-loops. But I think there are more elegant ways to do this in C++.

Comment: dont confuse loops with "pure C". If you look at implementations of standard algorithms, most of them are nothing more than a loop

Comment: There's probably a wiz that will tell you how to put some unreadable mess of template and lambdas together that and claim it's more "elegant". But readable code that is already working always trumps elegant code.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, I know :) But they are heavily optimized and work in the background.

Comment: Heavily optimized?  Maybe.  Works in the background?  No.

Comment: main optimization is from what the compiler does to them, and the compiler will do similar to your handwritten algo. Anyhow, sorry for going slightly offtopic. If you show a [mcve] of your code the question would be easier to answer.

Comment: @random9 - This will be a lot easier if you could show your existing code. As I study your problem, I don't really know what you mean by "along an axis".